# Why is this partial specialization? (And what can I do?)

Tags: c++, templates, g++

I have several member functions of a template class which are templates themselves. For all of them, the compiler complains: `error: function template partial specialization is not allowed`.

But I do not see why this should be a partial specialization. What can I do to achieve what I wrote in the code below?

```
template <int DIM>
class A : public B
{

    public:

        template <class T>
        T getValue(void* ptr, int posIdx);

        template <class T>
        T getValue(void* ptr, int posIdx, int valIdx);

        template <class T>
        T getValue(void* ptr, Coords& coord, Coords& size, int valIdx);

        template <class T>
        void setValue(void* ptr, int posIdx, T val);

        template <class T>
        void setValue(void* ptr, int posIdx, int valIdx, T val);

        template <class T>
        void setValue(void* ptr, Coords& coord, Coords& size, int valIdx, T val);

};

// example how the functions are implemented:
template <int DIM>
template <class T>
T A<DIM>::getValue<T>(void* ptr, Coords& coord, Coords& size, int valIdx){
  T val = static_cast<T>(some_value); // actually, its more complicated
  return val;
}
```

Comment: I think what you are doing wrongly is not shown, please paste the way you define those member functions. You probably define them as `T A<DIM>::getValue<T>(void* ptr, int posIdx)`, whilst you should type `T A<DIM>::getValue(void* ptr, int posIdx)`

Comment: @tobi303 Probably like `a.getValue<int>(...)`.

Comment: @JosephMansfield Never saw something like that. If this is working, I seriously have to review templates

Comment: Your code [compiles without errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8f5017aa1b7f010). Please provide a mcve. You haven't specialized any template in your code so there isn't any partial specializations either.

Comment: @KerrekSB yep, I was terribly wrong with my comment and I better deleted it not to spread nonsense. At least I could learn something from it ;)

Comment: @PiotrS.: You are perfectly right. That was how I did and it caused the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that, as your compiler says, you are trying to partially specialize a function template:

```
template <int DIM>
template <class T>
T A<DIM>::getValue<T>(void* ptr, Coords& coord, Coords& size, int valIdx){
//            here^^^
  T val = static_cast<T>(some_value); // actually, its more complicated
  return val;
}
```

You don't need to specialize the function here, just define it normally:

```
template <int DIM>
template <class T>
T A<DIM>::getValue(void* ptr, Coords& coord, Coords& size, int valIdx){
//     no more <T>^
  T val = static_cast<T>(some_value); // actually, its more complicated
  return val;
}
```